# how can it be that this SQL Query work from Oracle SQL Developer but not from code?

Tags: c#, sql, oracle

i have the following SQL query that works fine (returns multiple rows) when i run it from Oracle's SQL developer tool:

```
select * from  [schema].[table] where resource_unique_name in ('abc123') and (slice_date >= '01-Nov-10') and (slice_date < '01-Dec-10')
```

but somehow this code below returns 0 records (no errors just, 0 records):

```
 OracleDataReader reader = new OracleDataReader();
 const string CONNECTION_STRING = [myConnetionString];

 connection.ConnectionString = CONNECTION_STRING;
 connection.Open();

 OracleCommand command = connection.CreateCommand();
 command.CommandText = [same SQL as above];

 OracleDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();

 int rowCount = 0;
 while (reader.Read())
 {
      rowCount++;
 }
 Console.Write(rowCount);
```

the connection open's fine because if i hard code a different SQL query i do get results.

is there any reason a query would work fine in SQL query tool but not from my C# code ??

**UPDATED NOTE:**
in my code, when i remove the:

```
and (slice_date < '01-Dec-10')
```

it seems to work fine ( i get data back).  Any clue whats wrong with the above criteria ??

Comment: Are you sure you are connecting to the same database? Are there any private synonyms defined? Do you pass the dates hardcoded and in this format (`dd-mon-yyyy`)

Comment: Take a look at this similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1534250/c-connecting-to-oracle-db-datetime-formatting

Comment: It could be that PLSQL and your application use different connection settings that result in (amongst others) different date formats. But I would expect an error in that case. It is nonetheless a good thing to use parameters instead of hardcoded values.

Comment: @GolezTrol  - i added a new point to the question which should clarify that

Comment: Relying on implicit date conversions using the default settings for NLS parameters usually does that to you. What happens if you use TO_DATE function on your date string?

Comment: What happens if you remove the conditions?  I'd reduce it to "select * from  [schema].[table] where resource_unique_name" and see if you can get results from that.

Comment: @pm_2 - as per my question, removing the second criteria and everything works

Comment: @ooo: if removing that line of code is the solution, you should go ahead and write as an answer.

Comment: @dboarman - but removing part of my SQL code is NOT the answer.  I still need to find out how to replicate the query WITH these conditions

Comment: Does the TO_DATE suggestion work?

Comment: @GolezTrol: you won't get an error if Oracle can still parse the value to something unexpected; I'd guess here the client is using `DD-MON-RRRR' or `DD-MON-YYYY`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use ANSI date literals rather than just strings for the date values:

```
select * from [schema].[table]
where resource_unique_name in ('abc123') 
and slice_date >= date '2010-11-01' 
and slice_date < date '2010-12-01'
```

Answer (score 5):

I will answer the last part in your update.

`'01-Dec-10'` is a string. It is not a date. It has nothing to do with dates. Not until it gets converted into a date. There are (to my knowledge) three ways of doing that.

1. Use TO_DATE()
2. Specify a date literal as `date '2010-12-01'`, which is always iso date YYYY-MM-DD
3. Rely on implicit date conversion using the NLS settings (which you are doing)

If your NLS settings is `'DD-MON-RR'`, the string '01-Dec-10' would get converted into 2010-12-01 (*the 1st of december, 2010*). If, on the other hand, your settings are `'RR-MON-DD'`, it would be converted into `'2001-12-10'` (*the 10:th of december, 2001*).

I don't know your settings, and since you don't either, you should do the right thing, and that is to always explicitly use TO_DATE() or date literals.

Comment: when i try #2 (inside Oracle SQL developer), i get an error stating: literals in the input must be the same length as literals in the format string. are these settings set on the client side ??

Comment: @ooo: You need the `date` keyword before the literal, as shown in Tony's example. Without it, it still tries to interpret the string using your default date format, which appears to be `DD-MON-RR` in SQL Developer.

Comment: @ooo, did you write it as DATE '2010-12-01'?

Comment: now its working with 'Date' in front  . .thank you very much for your help